# How does a term algebra differ from a Herbrand structure?

Tags: model-theory

How does a term algebra differ from a Herbrand structure? Is it the same thing but with a subtle distinction between constant symbols and variable symbols that is not visible on the structure itself?

---

In Wilfrid Hodges' *A Shorter Model Theory*, the notion of a *term algebra* is introduced on page 14.

Let $L$ be any signature and $X$ a set of variables.

The domain is the set of terms in $L$ where all the variables are in $X$.

These are the equations that then define our term algebra.

$$ c^A =c \;\; \text{for each constant $c$ of $L$ }$$
$$ F^A(t) = F(t) \;\; \text{for each $n$-ary function $F$ of $L$ and $n$-tuple $t$ of elements in the domain of $A$ } $$
$$R^A \;\text{is empty} \;\; \text{for each relation symbol $R$ of $L$} $$

Then Hodges says that this definition is equivalent to the **absolutely free $L$-structure with basis $X$**.

---

I am really confused by this definition. If $A$ is our structure, then the domain of $A$ makes sense. They are finite strings of symbols where the alphabet is the language of $L$ and all the variables are in $X$.

In order to supply an interpretation for each of our constant symbols, we send them to themselves. The interpretation of every function symbol sends its arguments to the new term headed by that function. So the interpretation of each function is just *what that function does syntactically*.

The handling of relations doesn't make sense to me. I don't know why we picked that every relation is always false instead of being always true. I also don't know why we didn't just insist up front that $L$ has no relation symbols or simply impose no constraints on the relation symbols. Earlier in chapter, Hodges has commented explicitly on the arbitrariness of a given definition when making an arbitrary choice, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

The other thing that confuses me about it is how it differs from a Herbrand structure. I am only vaguely aware of what a Herbrand structure is. I have seen the definition before, but no nontrivial uses of it.

The idea in term algebras that every function's semantics are just what that function does to terms syntactically seems to be the same as with [Herbrand structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure).

Herbrand structures, however, do not have the equivalent of $X$, some extra variable symbols that are *injected* into our language, so to speak.

However, reading the definition of a term algebra carefully, it is not clear to me that a variable symbol and a constant symbol are actually *treated differently* by the term algebra construction. I don't think there a way to tell whether a given symbol was a constant or was a variable just by looking at the term algebra on its own.

Comment: It seems two different questions. For the first one, we usually indeed assume that there are no relation symbols in $L$. However, it does make sense to interpret the relations as empty in order to obtain a *free* $L$-structure.

Comment: to flesh out @Berci's point slightly: if $A$ is the absolutely free $L$-structure with basis $X$ as defined by Hodges, and $B$ is another $L$-structure, then any set map from $X$ to $B$ can be (uniquely) extended to an $L$-embeddings from $A$ to $B$. on the other hand, if $A$ has a non-empty relation symbol, then this is no longer true, since you need to ensure that the assignment of $X$ will map the relations in $A$ into the relations in $B$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom ... I see. So the relations in $A$ have to be empty because we picked we specify where relations are *true* in our semantics rather than specifying where they are *false* (we could specify where they are false, but that's not the convention). As for uniquely extending maps, ... is there a (well-motivated) category in which $A$ is an initial object?

Comment: oops, to correct a typo; I mean to say $L$-*homomorphism* above, and not $L$-embedding. re: your second question: the "right" categorical perspective on $A$ is that it is the "[free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) on $X$" in the category $\mathbf{C}$ of $L$-structure and $L$-homomorphisms; its universal property in this category is that $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(A,B)\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X,B)$$ for any object $B$ of $\mathbf{C}$, where in the latter hom-set we abuse notation and use $B$ to refer to its underlying set.

Comment: this is a special case of what's known as a "free-forgetful" adjunction, if you are familiar with that language. nb however that $A$ is *not* an initial object in $\mathbf{C}$: assuming you do not allow empty structures, then it *is* true that $A$ will have a morphism to every object of $\mathbf{C}$, but this morphism will *not* be unique in general, and in fact in general $A$ will have *many* morphisms to an object of $\mathbf{C}$. on the other hand, recall than an initial object in a category must have *precisely* one morphism to each other object, and no more

Comment: for your first question: yes! that's exactly right :) ... the main point is that an $L$-homomorphism needs only preserve relations in *one direction*. more precisely, if $R$ is an $n$-ary relation, and $A,B$ are $R$-structures, then a set map $f: A\to B$ is by definition an $R$-homomorphism if and only if we have $$A\models R(a_1,\dots,a_n)\implies B\models R(f(a_1),\dots,f(a_n))$$ for all $a_i\in A$. the implication here only goes in the forwards direction, not the backwards, and so $f$ only has the "worry" about tuples of $A$ that satisfy $R$, and not tuples of $A$ that don't